# In MDN site, why does it say Object.prototype inherits from Function.prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

I understand that Object.prototype.**proto** = null being end of the chain (so says the browsers console).

In MDN site, at the Object.prototype page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

At the bottom of the page, under "Inheritance:" you will see "Function" with expandable properties & method underneath. To my understanding it says Object.prototype inherits methods such as Function.prototype.bind() etc

I can understand the Object constructor function shares the non-prototypal property/method (such as caller property) as it is constructed by the Function constructor fn. But how does Object.prototype inherit from Function.prototype while Object.prototype.**proto** is null?

Can someone shed a light please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's referring to what the `Object` constructor inherits from, not object instances. All constructors are functions, so the `Object` function *itself* inherits from `Function.prototype`.

When you see the notice down a bit on the page that says:

> Properties inherited from Function:
>   arity, caller, constructor, length, name

It's easier to understand what was meant by that -- it's referring to how properties such as `Object.constructor` and `Object.length` have been inherited from `Function`.

Anyway, it *is* true that `Object.prototype.__proto__ === null` -- Object.prototype does not inherit from Function.prototype at all, as you had thought.

Comment: So as for the MDN site, is it another way of saying, that you can inherit the Function.prototype as an option, that is by overriding the Object.prototype?

Comment: @Charles: nope. `Object` is a constructor, which is a special type of function. We're talking about the properties on the _function_ here.